# Make categories appear random

Tags: posts, categories

I have 5 big categories and there are many small categories in them. If I click on the category menu, I can see the posts in order of date. But I want it to be displayed randomly. How can I make a post appear randomly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hook into the [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) action hook and set the posts' order to random only for specific categories. Here's a basic example on how to achieve so:

```
function sort_posts_randomly( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ( is_category( 'category id, slug, or name' ) ) { 
            // Sort the posts randomly
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'rand' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'sort_posts_randomly' );
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can pass an array of categories to `is_category()`, for example: `is_category ( array ( 'slug1', 'slug2' ) )` and so on.